# C# Dataset or not?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm a bit confused by the Dataset concept in C# (coding ASP.NET sites, not that it matters).  In my reading I'm understanding that they are used (essentially) as interfaces between my app and my data (or database).  I get that.  What I don't understand is some articles refer to datasets as "offline storage" where updates (inserts, etc...) are applied in batch or never, and others play more to the "interface" aspect, where reads and updates (inserts, etc...) are applied immediately to the underlining database.

Can someone please explain datasets in simple terms?  Do I want to really use them?  Maybe some short example cases might clear it up for me.  Otherwise, I don't see why I cannot just create a simple Class that selects, inserts, updates from my database, why would I care about some XML layer?

Your wisdom is appreciated.

Comment: It's a bit of a stab in the dark unless you explain the needs of your project. You've considered and rejected Entity Framework and need the additional cruft of dealing directly with Dataset instead, right?

Comment: FWIW, I use DataSets as a convenient collection of tables...nothing more. There are a great many capabilities built into DataSets, but most needs are better suited to an ORM and/or simpler data access (e.g. ExecuteScalar, ExecuteNonQuery, a DataReader).

Comment: I understand now. Most of the responses clarified it for me, so i cannot mark any one as the answer. I know my question was vague, but so was my understanding.  Great answers.

Answer (score 6):

It is a tool, and it has some handy features - sometimes they are fine, but frankly I use them very very rarely personally - usually preferring simple POCOs via things like dapper (or your own preferred ORM / micro-ORM - whatever).

The main time that `DataSet` / `DataTable` is useful is if you are creating something that *is itself dynamic* - for example, like [Stack Exchange Data Explorer](https://data.stackexchange.com/) - basically tools where the **schema coming back** is user-defined.

In most line-of-business software, this is simply not the case - so `DataTable` is not IMO the go-to tool.

Comment: +1, and yet even now with the `dynamic` type that can be worked around yes? I'm not sure on the performance implications though.

Comment: @neoistheone I will happily use `dynamic` *if there is data/usage locality* - i.e. if a DAL method requests two columns then consumes those columns locally - then great. If it exposes the data outside of the DAL, then I'd use a POCO. For the "dynamic schema" scenario, frankly it isn't worth re-inventing the wheel - `DataTable` works and gets that mostly right

Comment: @MarcGravell - I noticed that the dynamic version of Dapper is actually faster than the static version, was that a typo on the GitHub page or not?

Comment: @Karl would need more context and a very specific test - it'll be very similar in most scenarios. My main point here was actually about correctness (compiler checking etc) and discovery (what members exist?).

Comment: @MarcGravell - going from the `Performance of SELECT mapping over 500 iterations - POCO serialization` and `Performance of SELECT mapping over 500 iterations - dynamic serialization` charts from the GitHub page, it shows 49ms for POCO serialization and 48ms for dynamic serialization.

Comment: @KarlAnderson which is within the bracket I would call "pretty much the same, give or take" - that number does the job of comparing it to other ORMs and raw ADO.NET, simply to get a rough "about here" figure. If you want more precise measures to compare POCO to `dynamic`, you'd need a more conclusive test - but note that the exact result could depend on the particular test data etc.

Comment: @MarcGravell - fair enough, I was just blown away that `dynamic` was in the same ballpark, let alone potentially faster. Need to look into `dynamic` a little more.

Comment: @Karl don't forget we're measuring materialisation cost here; it doesn't include any downstream member-resolution overheads, but these will be slightly higher for dynamic than for static. But dynamic is actually heavily optimized.

Answer (score 3):

A DataSet is, from one perspective, an in-memory database.  The DataSet object certainly has its uses, and can be used to increase performance, make certain tasks much simpler, etc.  Whether or not to use it depends on the situation.  It's a tool that works well in some cases and not as well as alternatives in others.

One example of a scenario where a DataSet is a huge performance increase is in situations where you need to make multiple computations over a set of data.  I/O is still a major bottleneck to performance, and it can be the case that loading a dataset into memory, and performing functions such as Sum(), Avg(), etc using [DataTable.Compute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatable.compute.aspx) is far better performance-wise than executing multiple similar statements against a true database, requiring a round-trip to the DB server on each calculation.

That's just one scenario.  In a real-life application, I had to modify a program written by a previous developer, which made a connection to a Sybase SQL Anywhere function to perform multiple calculations on a sales data set.

I re-factored it to load the data once and do all computations in memory.  I cannot guarantee this type of performance enhancement at all, but the program went from taking literally over 24 hours to do a batch of calculations to under five minutes.

Answer (score 2):

You could use an [ORM Tool](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-relational_mapping) like [NHibernate](http://nhforge.org/) or [Entity Framework](http://www.asp.net/entity-framework). With this kind of approuch you just send a object of your domain (for sample: `Customer` or `Product`) to some objects of the ORM Tool and it will save on database to you. You do not need to write a SQL command to do it, the ORM tool just do it for you easly. With an ORM you just map your domain object in a class and it will manage for you on database, like this imagem (I know it is in java, but the concept is the same for an ORM tool):

[image]

On the other hand, you have ADO.NET internally and you can just write it, you will need to write some code, but it is not difficult.

There are a lot of reasons to does not use Dataset on .net, take a look on this article:
https://web.archive.org/web/20210125132705/https://www.4guysfromrolla.com/articles/050405-1.aspx

Answer (score 1):

I would not use a `DataSet`. In general I deal with POCO's (Plain Old CLR Object) and use a library like [Dapper](http://code.google.com/p/dapper-dot-net/) to `SELECT`, `INSERT`, `UPDATE`, and `DELETE` data from the database. It's so much easier to just use a basic object that mimics my database (a domain-model if you will) and do what I need.

There are a number of examples on Dapper's site that show you how to use POCO's with Dapper.

For simple projects I just leverage ADO.NET features (e.g. `ExecuteNonQuery`, `ExecuteScalar`, `ExecuteReader`) off of the standard `SqlCommand` object. Which also doesn't need a `DataSet`.

Comment: "POCO" = "Plain Old CLR Object"

Comment: @JoeEnos, LOL, all these years I've been using the wrong acronym!

Comment: Reminds me of the urban legend (who knows if it's true) of the person who convinced their parent/grandparent that LOL means "Lots of Love", and they started using it as a condolence on Facebook when someone's family member had died.

Answer (score 0):

a simple answer would be

> Datasets are disconnected, thus meaning you have a table-like structure in memory.