# Datasets and ASP.Net sites

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, dataset, poco

This morning i was discussing with one of my collegues some ASP.Net topics. Since i am used to desktop applications i wasn't aware that it is regarded as bad style to use DataSets in ASP.Net for connections with databases. My collegue couldn't explain to me why it is regarded as bad style(*his school-teacher always said so*) so i wondered if anybody here could explain what the problem with Datasets is.
I assumed that Datasets are a smart choice because they implement IXmlSerializable and ISerializable and are handy for APIs or something.
I think that it is regarded as bad style because of the size but as I mentioned i am no specialist in this topic area.

I read this article before: [C# Dataset or not?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18599663/c-sharp-dataset-or-not)
but it doesn't really clarify to me why somebody would say DataSets are bad style for ASP.Net. I don't want to be to broad so i am using here a hypothetical case

*So here is a hypothetical case:*

My Database is a **MS SQL Server Express 2012** and i am using the **.Net Framework 4.0**.
Let's say i have an online shop with 6000 customers and about 46000 items. What would be the best choice if i wanted to implement this in **ASP.Net and C#.** Should i use DataSets, POCOs or are DataTables the best choice to use my Data in the online shop ? Maybe there is a standard way to do this which is regarded as way to go.

As mentioned I don't have an actual problemcase, I am just curious.

Comment: Datasets are ok, but kind of outdated. I recommend using Entity Framework, read up on Datasets vs EntityFramework to get a better view.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most people over the last decade have used an ORM such as EntityFramework or NHibernate to bypass the need to write relatively low-level code with ADO.NET's `DataSet` and `DataTable`. It also does not convey business intent (although you could argue this is not important at this level of the application). Basically, you shouldn't need to write the code to populate a dataset as there are many other options available these days that do the job for you without having to write similar code over and over again. That said and although far from being a perfect solution, in most scenarios for small/medium sized projects `DataSet` works fine, as does an ORM. In the hypothetical situation you have provided, you could probably still use `DataSet` or an ORM without too many problems.

The problems arise when you want to scale your site when it becomes bigger or when you have spikes in traffic. From what you have mentioned in the question, it sounds like you are still using the "classic" N-Tier architecture. Many technologies have been developed in the last few years which try to work with the Web as opposed to the way we want the Web to work. Look at document databases (MongoDB, RavenDB, CouchDB), microservices architecture and CQRS (with Event Sourcing). There are no silver bullets (excuse the cliche) but at least you see there are many options that differ from the architectures that were considered ideal less than a decade ago.